# How to change YEAR label on flatpickr calendar

Tags: flatpickr

i want to change current label year on flatpickr calendar.
2019 to 2562, 2562 is buddhist year (+543 years).

[flatpickr calendar picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0pHk.png)

```js
flatpickr.localize(flatpickr.l10ns.th);

$('#my_date').flatpickr({
  dateFormat: "Y-m-d 20:00",
  altInput: true,
  onChange: (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => {
    moment.locale('th');
    thai_DM = moment(selectedDates[0]).format('Do MMMM');
    thai_Y = parseInt(moment(selectedDates[0]).format('YYYY')) + 543;
    instance.altInput.value = thai_DM + " " + thai_Y;
    $('#dateStr_for_db').val(dateStr);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- flatpickr -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr/dist/l10n/th.js"></script>

<!-- moment -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="my_date"> flatpickr
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="dateStr_for_db"> my_date.value for insert to db
```

i write some line to make alternate text for Thai readable and still have
BC. date for DB.
almost done. but i cant change year label on the calendar.
Please help :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this problem, but finaly I just shift current date of 543 years and before saving shift back. I am using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/).

```
toBudThai(date) {
    return (date.clone()).add(543, "years");
}

fromBudThai(date) {
    return (date.clone()).subtract(543, "years");
}

getDefaultDate() {
    return this.toBudThai(moment());
}
```

Flatpickr options looks like this.

```
{
    ...
    defaultDate: getDefaultDate().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    onChange: (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => {
        if (selectedDates.length) {
            console.log( fromBudThai(moment(selectedDates[0])) );        
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by getting the `flatpickr` instance and changing the year:

```
let instant = $(".datepickernextyear").flatpickr({
                "locale": "th",
                "dateFormat": "d/m/Y"
            });
            
 //set calendar to buddhist +543
 instant.changeYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 543)
```